# Using ggplot to reflect uneven spacing between time points

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, line-plot, longitudinal

I am plotting for longitudinal trjaectories, which are latent trajectories from the results of Growth Mixture modelling. My data were collected at uneven distributed time points, say age 13,15,17,21,24,27. I would like my graph to reflect that uneven spcaing, i.e., "stretched" for larger age gaps.

I have tried using scale_x_continuous, and ensured sweep (timepoints) is numeric. In the result plot, the labels were correct,but still had equal distance from each other.

```
age <- c(13,15,17,21,24,27)
p  <- ggplot(long_dta, aes(Sweep, value, group=numericID, colour=gmm2_grp)) 
+ geom_line() + geom_smooth(aes(group= gmm2_grp), method="loess", size=2, se=F)  
+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,40)) 
+ scale_x_continuous(labels = age) 
+ labs(x="Age(years)",y="total_score",colour="Latent Class")
```

[image: the x-axis with my current code]

As you can see, there's 1 "grid" between 3 and 5, 5 and 7, which are making perfect sense. But in that case, there should be 3 "grids" between 7, and 11, so on and so forth.

I would sincerely appreciate any suggestions on how I can reflect the uneven distribution of timepoints on my plot.

Comment: The issue is most likely that the variable `Sweep` does not reflect the uneven distribution of `age`. If you already have a column age in your data map this variable on x or add such a column to your data. For more help please provide provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: Is `is.numeric(long_dta$Sweep)` indeed `TRUE`?

Comment: It very much appears that `Sweep` is a factor variable. Try `aes(as.numeric(as.character(Sweep)), value,  group=numericID, colour=gmm2_grp))`. This will use the numeric value of the label of the factor.

Comment: Thank you, stefan and I_O, and Jon Spring! Sweep is a numeric variable, but as stefan mentioned, it does not directly reflect age. I added a variable with ages and used that to create axes, which effectively resolved my problem!